# Questions regarding Spivak's 4th Ed. Calculus: Problem 26d of Chapter 19

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

The following question is derived from Chapter 19 Problem 26d of Spivak's 4th Ed. *Calculus*.

Specifically, I have proven the following statements:

- $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0^+}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx=\pi$
- $\displaystyle \left|f_0\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx-f_0\int_{-d}^{d}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx \right| \lt \alpha$, where $\alpha$ and $f_0$ are just constants, $\alpha \gt 0$, and $|d|\lt 1$

**How do I go about proving that**:

$$\left|\pi f_0-f_0\int_{-d}^{d}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx\right| \lt \alpha$$

---

Obviously, as $h$ gets small (while remaining strictly positive), $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$ approaches $\pi$. Moreover, because $h$ is positively restricted, $\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}$ is a strictly positive (and even) function which means that $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx \gt \int_{-d}^{d}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$. As $h$ approaches $0$ from the right and $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$ approaches $\pi$, *something* is also happening to the value of $\int_{-d}^{d}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$. But what that something *is*, I am not really sure. Without the ability to categorize these rates of change of $\int_{-d}^{d}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$ and $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$, it's not clear to me if $\int_{-d}^{d}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$ is  'keeping pace with' $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx$ as we move the positive $h$ closer and closer to $0$. If could prove this, then I would feel pretty confident that $\left|\pi f_0-f_0\int_{-d}^{d}\frac{h}{h^2+x^2}dx\right| \lt \alpha$ follows.

I am tempted to take the derivative with respect to $h$ of the integrals...but this book has not provided me with the means of performing this calculation, so I am sort of stumped.

Comment: I think there's some information missing: For example if $\alpha=0$, then obviously this is not true in general. Also, if $d\geq 1$ then I don't see why $\int_{-1}^1>\int_{-d}^d$. Could you clarify what the roles of $\alpha$, $d$ and $f_0$ are?

Comment: @Jose27 sure, sure. I will clarify both in the post. ($\alpha \gt 0$ and $|d|\lt 1$)